# Debezium SQL Server source connector skipping records after Connector restart

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I m using Debezium CDC SQL Server source connector to take data from the SQL server and put it in Kafka
the configurations I m using are

```
name=ds1
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
tasks.max=1
database.server.name=server2
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=1433
database.user=sa
database.password=Password!
database.dbname=demo
#table.whitelist=mytable
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=schema-changes.demo
```

when I restart my connector with the same name the data which was produced now is not picked up by connector,
Is there anything I m doing wrong, or do I need to add some other configuration for my connector?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the expected behaviour. Kafka Connect will use the name of the connector to store the offsets from which data in the source system has been read. When the connector is restarted Kafka Connect will not re-process data that has already been read, otherwise you'd end up with unwanted duplicates.

If you want to actually reprocess existing data the simplest way is to create the connector with a new name.

Comment: yeah thats correct, But after loading the connector with the same name, if i try to insert records now in the database table, those new records are also not picked up by connector, is it also a known behaviour

Comment: are there any errors in your Kafka Connect worker log?